# Auto-activate conda env when changing directory

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, environment

I have few conda environments that I use in different projects, say:

- ml37 (for machine learning)
- etl37 (for data pipelines)

I have local projects organized in their own directories:

- apps/some_app
- apps/other_app
- ...

Each time I `cd` to a specific project, I already know which env I would like to use. So I end up doing `conda activate [some env]` each time I change directories. I feel like there must be a better way.

What would be a clean way to automatize this?

Or is my use of conda environments wrong?

Answer (score 8):

I made a script similar to the one of Corey Chafer, but this one extends the cd command.

```
cd() { builtin cd "$@" && 
if [ -f $PWD/.conda_config ]; then
    export CONDACONFIGDIR=$PWD
    conda activate $(cat .conda_config)
elif [ "$CONDACONFIGDIR" ]; then
    if [[ $PWD != *"$CONDACONFIGDIR"* ]]; then
        export CONDACONFIGDIR=""
        conda deactivate
    fi
fi }
```

Put this few lines of code at the bottom of your shell profile and then create a .conda_config file inside the directory you want to activate the env for.
The .conda_config file must contain only the env name.

In this way, every time you cd into a directory that has a .conda_config file, the script will activate the env, and every time you cd out it will deactivate.

I created a repo for reference [Conda-autoactivate-env](https://github.com/vallops99/Conda-autoactivate-env)

EDIT:
There was a bug in the `elif` condition.
Basically `[-n $CONDACONFIGDIR]` returns always True and its logic is backwards actually.

The fix is:
quote the variable (or use double squared brackets) and remove -n
`[ "$CONDACONFIGDIR" ]` OR `[[ $CONDACONFIGDIR ]]`.

The above code is already up-to-date!

Comment: Confirming it's working great for me. Cheers.

Comment: Nice try! but it won't work with,

1. ZSH where we just type directory name to switch
2. Opening a new terminal tab on the same directory

I switched to `pyenv` and `pyenv-virtualenv` instead which works flawlessly.
Here is an article on how to setup and configure pyenv. 

https://www.andreagrandi.it/2022/01/29/install-python-with-pyenv-and-pyenvvirtualenv-create-virtual-environment-with-specific-python-version-macos/

Comment: Alright, but we're working with Conda there.
Anyway, thanks for raising this issue, I'll try to add these features.

Comment: This is superb, but I encourage you to submit it as an enhance at https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues so they can make it standard at least for Mac, and at least with certain shells.

Comment: That's a smart move, didn't think about it.
So, I'm checking around conda's repositories, do you think anaconda-issues is the right repo to open an issue?
I'm asking that because I see that I can open an issue for "package update" and "new package", and there we are not talking about a specific package.
Maybe they could create a new package to be installed in conda? So I should put it in "new package" section.
Let me know what do you think, I'm still not sure of what I just said.

Comment: I normally use `pyenv` and I am now using `conda` to replicate a production workflow, and I see this as a major shortcoming with `conda`. Note this GH issue which is relevant: https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/5179

Comment: I agree with you about it being a major shortcoming.
Thanks for pointing out the GH issue, I'll add in it the same I wrote here. Hopefully, someone will point out how to properly bring the script to the attention of Conda's developers and they will find it useful.

Comment: Instead of extending the `cd()` command you can add this to your `.zshrc`


`autoload -U add-zsh-hook
add-zsh-hook chpwd auto_activate_conda_env`

where `auto_activate_conda_env` is your script for activating coda environ